# How to output terminal command into a widget in OSX dashboard?

Tags: macos, emacs, iterm2, dashboard

I want to have a way of outputting a terminal command, like:

```
$ cat todo.org | awk '{ print $1 }' > dashboard_widget
```

Into a dashboard widget, not necessarily the text output of a command. Maybe a "iTerm2" dashboard that only outputs but doesn't get input from the user.

What I want to do with this is to have the output of a emacs buffer with my todo list.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Don't know where to start. Already googled by didn't find any solution.

Comment: My suggestion: Set up a cron or launchd job to periodically transform your todo list like in the example you provided into an output file. Display that file's contents in a widget by getting a script's (`cat` comes to mind) output. [This should help](http://andrew.hedges.name/widgets/dev/). Dashcode is part of Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are dashboard widgets that execute shell scripts and display the output.

Examples:

- http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/networking_security/shellwatcher.html
- http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/quickcommand.html

Your script can call emacs in batch mode to preprocess and export your `todo.org` into plain text mode, or you can use your `awk` preprocessing instead.